# Raster Channeling in Google Colab

Tags: python

I am encountering a problem in channeling(RGB) the images in Google Colab. I used the Gdrive as my source path. I am analyzing a raster images. I don't have a background in image processing and kinda hard for me to follow youtube tutorial because of language barrier. I'm not good at comprehending english language, plus the fact that they have different accent. I am sorry in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image
image1 = Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/UNIT3/eagle.jpg")#this is the error.
plt.figure( figsize = (5,5) )

red = image1[:, :, 0]
green = image1[:, :, 1]
blue = image1[:, :, 2]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

cax_00 = axs[0,0].imshow(image1)
axs[0,0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())  
axs[0,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())  
cax_01 = axs[0,1].imshow(red, cmap='Reds')
fig.colorbar(cax_01, ax=axs[0,1])
axs[0,1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
axs[0,1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())

cax_10 = axs[1,0].imshow(green, cmap='Greens')
fig.colorbar(cax_10, ax=axs[1,0])
axs[1,0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
axs[1,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())

cax_11 = axs[1,1].imshow(blue, cmap='Blues')
fig.colorbar(cax_11, ax=axs[1,1])
axs[1,1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
axs[1,1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
plt.show(image1)
```

error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0cda286700a0> in <module>()
----> 1 image1 = Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab 
Notebooks/UNIT3/eagle.jpg")#this is the error.
  2 
  3 
  4 red = image1[:, :, 0]
  5 green = image1[:, :, 1]

NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: I ran the above code (without the Colab commands) on Ubuntu Mate (not Colab) and I got this response: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 11, in <module>
    red = image1[:, :, 0]
TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not subscriptable
Any idea what to do?